# Тестирование. Как отправить json на клиент для проверки

Tags: javascript, vue.js, тестирование

Хочу отправить json-файл на клиент (с клиента) - протестить функцию. 
Как это лучше реализовать? Для аналогичной задачи на бэке я поднимал отдельный контейнер с unit-тестом. Что делать на фронте - не очень очевидно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать или поднять мок сервер. Например, https://github.com/typicode/json-server Из своего кода (с клиента) будете обращаться к нему. Он будет Вам присылать json какой скажете.

Comment: Я скачал приложение POSTMAN и вопрос уже решён.

Но ваш ответ может помочь - отмечу, спасибо